# how to hide YouTube controls using Wordpress video src

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I have read that you can use `controls=0` but it doesn't seem to work in my case:

Using `poster` shows a nice image instead of the video but I can still see the controls and if I click on the play button I actually get an error:

> The request contains an invalid parameter value. Verify that video ID
>   has 11 characters and that contains no invalid characters, such as
>   exclamation points or asterisks.

```
[video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyz123?controls=0" poster="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/someImg.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the second ? to &

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyz123&controls=0

Anytime you are passing multiple parameters via the URL it starts with ? but each one gets separated by &

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but the controls are still visible.